# re-hide conditional shiny output once it has been rendered

Tags: r, shiny

I need some help as to how to re-hide a shiny output once it has been rendered. Below I have provided a  reproducible example to explain my question.

I want text 2.2 to only be shown if Option 1 and B are selected, and text 1 to only show when option 2 is selected. I have done this by including  conditionalPanel() with the conditions set accordingly.

This works, however, once the text has been rendered this text will not disappear when the input changes.  I want text 2.2 to disappear if the user then changes the inputs to select any other option i.e. chooses Option 2.

Is it possible to do this with shiny? Apologies if this has been asked before - I couldn't find anything through searching - your help is much appreciated!

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Input1", label = "Input1", choices = c("Option 1", "Option 2") ),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Input1 == 'Option 1'",
                     selectInput("Input2", label = "Input2",
                                 choices = c("A", "B"))),
  ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Tab 1", textOutput(outputId = "text1")),

      tabPanel("Tab 2", textOutput(outputId = "text2.1"), textOutput(outputId = "text2.2") )
    )
  )


)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({if(input$Input1 == 'Option 2'){
    output$text1 <- renderText("This text only shows for option 2")
  }})


  output$text2.1 <- renderText("some text")

  observe({if(input$Input2 == 'B'){
    output$text2.2 <- renderText("Show this only if option 1B is selected")
  }})


} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the different `if` possiblities inside the `observe` environment. Here's a solution:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarPanel(
    selectInput("Input1", label = "Input1", choices = c("Option 1", "Option 2") ),
    conditionalPanel(condition = "input.Input1 == 'Option 1'",
                     selectInput("Input2", label = "Input2",
                                 choices = c("A", "B"))),
  ),

  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel("Tab 1", textOutput(outputId = "text1")),

      tabPanel("Tab 2", textOutput(outputId = "text2.1"), textOutput(outputId = "text2.2") )
    )
  )


)

server <- function(input, output) {

  observe({
    if(input$Input1 == 'Option 2'){
      output$text1 <- renderText("This text only shows for option 2")
      }
    else {
      output$text1 <- renderText("")
    }
    })


  output$text2.1 <- renderText("some text")

  observe({
    if (input$Input2 == "B") {
      output$text2.2 <- renderText("Show this only if option 1B is selected")
    }
    else {
      output$text2.2 <- renderText("")
    }
  })


} 

shinyApp(ui, server)
```