# Shiny refuses to draw charts despite there being Output

Tags: r, shiny

I wrote Shiny app but for some reason it shows no charts when I run it. I thought it might be due to no Output, but I double checked it and there is one. My uiOutput works perfectly fine and sidebar is also showing properly only this plotOutput is broken for an unknown reason.
Here is how the code looks like:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)

#test<-read.csv("C:/Users/pawel/Desktop/AWD/PROJEKT/moj.csv")
#View(test)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""), sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Aplikacja pokazująca dane odnośnie ludzi, którzy ulegli poważnym wypadkom oraz informacje o ich rezultacie"),
      tags$hr(),
      fileInput("file"," Proszę podać ścieżkę do pliku CSV: "), 
      selectInput("att", "Proszę wybrać wykres", choices=c("Dane początkowe ","Ranking 10 najlepszych producentów "," Sprzedaż gier w danym regionie ","Global Sales ","NA Sales ","EU Sales ","Japan Sales"," Other Sales"),
                  selected="Dane początkowe", multiple=FALSE,selectize=TRUE)
    ),
  mainPanel(
    uiOutput("tb"),
    plotOutput("line")             
  ))
)

#server.R
server <- function(input,output){
  
  data <- reactive({
    
    file1 <- input$file
    if(is.null(file1)){return()} 
    
    read.csv(file=file1$datapath, sep=",", header=TRUE)})

    output$filedf <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    input$file
  }) 

  output$sum <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    summary(data())
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    if(is.null(data())){return ()}
    data()
  })
  
  
  output$line <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(data())) { return() }
    
    
    else if(identical(input$att,"Dane początkowe")){
      print(ggplot(data(), aes(Genre, fill = as.factor(Genre) ) ) 
            + geom_bar() 
            + theme(text = element_text(size=20),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1)) 
            + labs(title = "Ilość tytułów, na których jest przeprowadzana analiza z każdego z gatunków", x="Gatunek", y="Ilość tytułów")      
      )}
    
    
    else if(identical(input$att,"Ranking 10 najlepszych producentów")){
      a<- as.data.frame(table(table$Publisher))
      a <- a[order(a$Freq),] 
      z<-nrow(a)
      x<-nrow(a)-9
      b<- a[x:z,]
      print(pie(b$Freq, b$Var1, col = rainbow(length(b$Freq)), main="Ranking 10 producentów, którzy wydali najwięcej gier")
      )
    }
    
    
    else if(identical(input$att,"Sprzedaż gier w danym regionie")){
      Region <- c("NA", "EU", "JP", "OTHER", "GLOBAL")
      Sales <- c(sum(table$NA_Sales), sum(table$EU_Sales), sum(table$JP_Sales), sum(table$Other_Sales), sum(table$Global_Sales))
      newd<- data.frame(Region, Sales)
      print(ggplot(newd, aes(x=Region, y=Sales)) + 
              geom_bar(stat="identity", width=.5, fill='darkgoldenrod1') 
            + labs(title="Sprzedaż gier w zależności od regionu ")
            + theme(text = element_text(size=20))
      )
    }
    
    
    else if(identical(input$att,"Global Sales")){
      print(ggplot(data(), aes(table$Genre, table$Global_Sales)) 
            + geom_boxplot(colour="red") 
            + theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))  
            + facet_wrap(~Platform)
      )
    }
    
    
    
    else if(identical(input$att,"NA Sales")){
      print(ggplot(data(), aes(table$Genre, table$NA_Sales)) 
            + geom_boxplot(colour="red") 
            + theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))  
            + facet_wrap(~Platform)
      )
    }
    
    else if(identical(input$att,"EU Sales")){
      print(ggplot(data(), aes(table$Genre, table$EU_Sales)) 
            + geom_boxplot(colour="red") 
            +   scale_colour_continuous()
            + theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))  
            + facet_wrap(~Platform)
      )
    }
    
    else if(identical(input$att,"Japan Sales")){
      print(ggplot(data(), aes(table$Genre, table$JP_Sales)) 
            + geom_boxplot(colour="red") 
            + theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))  
            + facet_wrap(~Platform)
      )
    }
    
    else if(identical(input$att,"Other Sales")){
      print(ggplot(data(), aes(table$Genre, table$Other_Sales)) 
            + geom_boxplot(colour="red") 
            + theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))  
            + facet_wrap(~Platform)
      )
    }
  })
  output$tb <- renderUI({if(is.null(data())) h5()
    else
      tabsetPanel(tabPanel("Informacje o wczytanym pliku", tableOutput("filedf")),
                  tabPanel("Wczytane dane", tableOutput("table")),
                  tabPanel("Podsumowanie wczytanych danych", tableOutput("sum")))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: How my app looks like]

As you can see it properly loads all the data yet still it refuses to load charts.

Comment: Have you tried removing `print` around `ggplot`?

Comment: Print definitely doesn’t help here, that forces the output to the console rather than to the app!

Comment: I did as you told me, but removing print changed nothing sadly.

Comment: hi, did you try to replace ```identical(input$att,"Other Sales")``` by ```input$att = "Other Sales"``` or other possible values for this input? Another idea is to detail every case in an ```observe``` environment (check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179865/re-hide-conditional-shiny-output-once-it-has-been-rendered/59182431#59182431) to see an example). Also, it would be much easier to help you if you included an example with data that everyone can use.

Comment: Your ggplot calls need to end the line with `+`, not begin.

Comment: I did that but sadly same effect. Still none of the charts is working and when I choose Japan I get this error: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable. On other charts it does not appear. Any ideas?

Comment: Nevermind guys I managed to fix it thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind guys I managed to fix it thanks for all help!
The problem was with random spacebards in selectInput